# Linq query for condition on one property for fetching record

Tags: c#, linq

var Data = // selecting some cloumns from postgresql using linq query

Data contain all propery of class A (Student Name,Subject Name & MarksObtained)

Data has following value

```
Student Name   Subject Name       MarksObtained
Rani           Maths              43
Rani           Physics            30
Manasa         Maths              39
Manasa         Physics            45
Aisharvya      Physics            47
```

Now I want to do further modification existing record.
When Subject is Maths and MarksObtained is greater than 40,should not appear/take that record.

Output like

```
 Student Name   Subject Name       MarksObtained
    Rani           Physics            30
    Manasa         Maths              39
    Manasa         Physics            45
    Aisharvya      Physics            47
```

How to do that?

Comment: This is basic Boolean logic. What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: Unable to write condition in where clause.I will create another variable or data in same variable.How to process with property name.

Comment: *"Unable to write condition in where clause"*. Then learn Boolean logic. If you have no idea at all then you need to make the effort to find out for yourself. If you do have some idea but what you're trying isn't working then you need to show us what you're trying and explain EXACTLY what happens. This is not a place where you tell us what you want and we write the code for you. You need to show us your best attempt. If you haven't attempted anything then you haven't encountered an issue yet.

Comment: If you understand Boolean logic but don't understand LINQ then you need to learn LINQ - the basics at least. Not knowing how to do something is not a specific issue. Not knowing a broad subject like Boolean logic or LINQ is not a specific issue. You don't have a specific issue until you learn the basics of the subject, make an effort to apply that knowledge and find that what you think should work does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var Data = YourList.Where(x => !(x.SubjectName == "Maths" && x.MarksObtained > 40));
```

Explanation: when you put something inside `( )`, all the stuff in there are considered as **one** statement. And the `!` suggests `Not` to the statement(s) inside `( )` (if they are Boolean expression, which they are in this case)

As jmcilhinney said in the comments, you must always try to figure out your problem on your own, not because of "carry your own burden", but because that's the only way you can learn. I'm only answering because I need some reputation points

I would appreciate it if you could accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
var list2 = list.Where(a => !string.Equals(a.subjectName, "Maths") || a.marksObtained < 40)
                .ToList();
```